# visual studio 2010 c++ :export data to excel

Tags: c++, excel, visual-studio-2010

In my project, I wish to export results in excel sheet or CSV format. In one of the tutorial project, the results are displayed using **CListCtrl** object. The header file of this code :

```
    #include "CProBlob.h"
    #include "CProBlobParamsResource.h"

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CBlobResultsPage dialog

    class CBlobResultsPage : public CDialog
    {
        //DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CBlobResultsPage)

    // Construction
    public:
        CBlobResultsPage(CWnd* pParentWnd, CProBlob* pBlob = NULL);
        ~CBlobResultsPage();

    // Dialog Data
        //{{AFX_DATA(CBlobResultsPage)
        enum { IDD = IDD_BLOB_RESULTS };
        CListCtrl   m_List;
        //}}AFX_DATA


    // Overrides
        // ClassWizard generate virtual function overrides
        //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CBlobResultsPage)
        public:
        virtual BOOL Create(CWnd* pParentWnd);
        protected:
        virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
        virtual void OnCancel( );
        //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

    // Implementation
    protected:
        // Generated message map functions
        //{{AFX_MSG(CBlobResultsPage)
        virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
        afx_msg void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);
        //}}AFX_MSG
        DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

    public:
       void UpdateList();

    private:
       void UpdateItem(int item, bool insert);
       void FitListToWindow();

    protected:
       CProBlob* m_pBlob;
       int m_ColumnCount;
    };

    //{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
    // Microsoft Visual C++ will insert additional declarations immediately before the previous line.

    #endif // !defined(AFX_BLOBRESULTSPAGE_H__A1AF73AA_E071_41D2_BA2E_40FCF16E8630__INCLUDED_)
///////////////////////////////////////
```

And corresponding cpp file is:

```
    BOOL CBlobResultsPage::OnInitDialog() 
    {
        CDialog::OnInitDialog();

       // Initialize icon from parent
       SetIcon(m_pParentWnd->GetIcon(FALSE), FALSE);
       SetIcon(m_pParentWnd->GetIcon(TRUE), TRUE);

        // Insert colums in the list (the first time only)
       if (!m_List.GetItemCount())
       {
          m_ColumnCount = 0;

          // Basic Blob Features
          m_List.InsertColumn(m_ColumnCount++, "Index");
          m_List.InsertColumn(m_ColumnCount++, "Area");
          m_List.InsertColumn(m_ColumnCount++, "BBoxArea");     

          m_List.SetExtendedStyle(m_List.GetExtendedStyle() | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_GRIDLINES);
       }

       UpdateList();
        FitListToWindow();

        return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                      // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
    }

    void CBlobResultsPage::UpdateList()
    {
       int numItems = __min(m_List.GetItemCount(), m_pBlob->GetNumBlobs());

       // Update already existing items
       int i;
       for (i=0; i < numItems; i++)
       {
          UpdateItem(i, false);
       }

       // Is the new list larger than the existing one?
       if (m_pBlob->GetNumBlobs() > m_List.GetItemCount())
       {
          // Insert new items at the end of the list
          for (; i < m_pBlob->GetNumBlobs(); i++)
          {
             UpdateItem(i, true);
          }
       }
       else
       {
          // Delete unused items
          int item = m_pBlob->GetNumBlobs();
          while (m_List.GetItemCount() > m_pBlob->GetNumBlobs())
          {
             m_List.DeleteItem(item);
          }
       }

       // Adjust columns width
       for (i=0; i < m_ColumnCount; i++)
          m_List.SetColumnWidth(i, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER);
    }

    void CBlobResultsPage::UpdateItem(int item, bool insert)
    {
       CString str;
       LPCTSTR NotComputedStr = "NC";
       int col = 1;

       // Index
       str.Format("%d", item);
       if (insert)
          m_List.InsertItem(item, str);
       else
          m_List.SetItemText(item, 0, str);

       // Blob Area
       str.Format("%d", (int)m_pBlob->GetArea(item));
       m_List.SetItemText(item, col++, str);

   // Blob BBox Area
   str.Format("%d", (int)m_pBlob->GetBBoxArea(item));
   m_List.SetItemText(item, col++, str);
    }
```

So far, I could modify code to open excel sheet using information given on [this website.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476238/Automating-Excel-and-creating-charts-using-Cp)

And wish to modify updatelist() function. But, I don't know corresponding functions in excel object.

1) how to get number of columns used. its type should be int.

2) how Can I auto increment column.

3) how to access cells in excel sheet in cell(i,j) format so I to be used inside for loop

```
    Updated code :
BOOL CBlobResultsPage::OnInitDialog() 
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();



   // Initialize icon from parent
   SetIcon(m_pParentWnd->GetIcon(FALSE), FALSE);
   SetIcon(m_pParentWnd->GetIcon(TRUE), TRUE);

    if(!AfxOleInit())
   {
       AfxMessageBox(_T("cannot initialise COM dll"));
       return FALSE;
   }

            COleVariant
      covTrue((short)TRUE),
      covFalse((short)FALSE),
      covOptional((long)DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);

        CApplication app;
        if(!app.CreateDispatch(TEXT("Excel.Application")))
        {
            AfxMessageBox(TEXT("Couldn't start excel and get application object"));
                return FALSE;
        }

        app.put_Visible(TRUE);
        app.put_UserControl(TRUE);


        books = app.get_Workbooks();
        book = books.Add(covOptional);


        //Get the first sheet.
        sheets =book.get_Sheets();
        sheet = sheets.get_Item(COleVariant((short)1));

        COleSafeArray saRet;
        DWORD numElements[]={1,3};   //4x1 element array
        saRet.Create(VT_BSTR, 2, numElements);


        FillSafeArray(L"Blob_no", 0, 0, &saRet);
        FillSafeArray(L"X-cor",0, 1, &saRet);
        FillSafeArray(L"Y-corr",0, 2, &saRet);

        range = sheet.get_Range(COleVariant(TEXT("A1")), COleVariant(TEXT("C1")));
        range.put_Value2(COleVariant(saRet));
        saRet.Detach();
        UpdateList();

return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: See the given link to learn more about how to use Excel objects. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194068(v=office.15).aspx